# How can I change the font family in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, pgfplots

I am using the `classicthesis` package in LyX to typeset my thesis. I have a plot produced with `pgfplots`. It uses math fonts same as elsewhere in the text, which is inconsistent with other plots of mine (imported from Matlab), where Arial is used for tick and axes labels. So my question is, how can I change the font family for the text used in my `pgfplots` plot (i.e. the caption font should NOT change)? The minimal TeX code would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
thick,
tick style={semithick}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=8cm,
width=15cm,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$\phi(x)$},
domain = 0:1,
xtick={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
ytick={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5},
grid=major,
no markers,
cycle list name=linestyles
]
\addplot {0.5-abs(x-0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Solution of Eikonal equation on a 1D domain $\Omega=[0;1]$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So I would like all the tick numbers, and `x` and `\phi(x)` labels to be in Arial, while the bottom caption to remain in Palatino.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply using `\pgfplotsset` and `\sffamily` is probably not sufficient for you, since your numbers and labels are in math mode. It can be achieved with the `sansmath` package, such as

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{
  tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}
}
```

You probably have still to take care of Greek letters though, if you use `eulervm`. Without that package, `\sansmath` works well. Or, omit sans serif style for the label, and do it manually at this specific place, such as

```
xlabel = {$\mathsf{x}$},
ylabel = {$\phi\mathsf{(x)}$},
```

All together I got with your code all labels in sans serif, while the caption remains in serif font:

[image: plot]

Comment: This is almost brilliant! But you are right, phi(x) looks very ugly. But how would I take care of it? And is there a way to make the labels non-italic?

Comment: @MindV0rtex Consider changing the Matlab plots to match your LaTeX style for keeping all consistent. Or keep at least labels such as `\phi(x)` similar to your expressions in code instead of trying sans serif Greek, at least the numbers and tick labels would match your Matlab style.

Comment: Mine is the same except for the `\phi(x)` part, which instead looks something like `OEx` without any parentheses (I don't know how to add pictures to comments and I don't want to add another answer). Does it mean that I lack some font files?

Comment: @MindV0rtex If you don't load `eulervm`, `\phi` works with `\sansmath`.

Comment: @stefan-kottwitz How can I use my font's sffamily? I have set it up like this: `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{mysf-font}` and when I use `font=\sffamily` it doesn't change accordingly.

Comment: How can I use `assume math mode=true` with `tick label style` do disable math mode?

Answer (score 3):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but I think it might be useful for others.

Following page 75 of the `pgfplots` manual (Revision 1.17 (2020/02/29))

```
\pgfplotsset{
  xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
  yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
}
```