# Using \sffamily for tick labels in pgfplots

Tags: fonts, pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the font family in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots)

I'm trying to use sf font for tick labels in pgfplots. I've already seen many questions like this, but all of them had more complex problems and I couldn't find the appropriate solution myself.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{helvet}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\pgfplotsset{
every axis label/.append style={font=\huge\sffamily},
tick label style={font=\sffamily\huge},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=8cm,
width=15cm,
xlabel = {x3456},
ylabel = {y},
domain = 0:1,
xtick={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
ytick={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5},
grid=major,
no markers,
cycle list name=linestyles
]
\addplot {0.5-abs(x-0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: MWE]

As you can see, `\sffamily` works for the *axis labels*, but not for the *tick labels*. Strangely, the `\huge` does work for the tick labels.

How do I change tick labels to `\sffamily`?

Comment: I think that the question [How can I change the font family in pgfplots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots/33329#33329) applies here. Could you try out that solution?

Comment: That's where I got my mwe from. They use math mode to use sans font. I think now I understand what is happening. Tick labels seem to be considered math expressions, so \sffamily doesn't work with them. So you have to use \sansmath. If someone can confirm this, I appreciate.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right. The tick labels are generated using `\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}`, which in turn uses math mode.

Answer (score 4):

If my comment regarding *tick labels* being considered math expressions is correct, you must use  math mode sans font to make them sans serif. On the other hand, *axis labels* are considered normal text, so you have to use  `\sffamily` to make them sans serif.

So, the solution would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{
tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=8cm,
width=15cm,
xlabel = {x3456},
ylabel = {y3456},
domain = 0:1,
xtick={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
ytick={0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5},
grid=major,
no markers,
cycle list name=linestyles
]
\addplot {0.5-abs(x-0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I don't know why, but using only

```
every axis label = {font=\sffamily\footnotesize}
```

does not work for me, so I had to use

```
every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize}.
```

With the above code, the output is

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to mark your question as duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots?lq=1 and maybe edit the answer over there to clarify the things that you didn't get correctly instead of stating a duplicate question an answer here?

Comment: I agree, but I had already posted the question when I figured it out. If there's a way to delete it, I'll do it, but I can't see how. Leaving it unanswered wouldn't help it either.