# Change font family in pgfplots (followup)

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, pgfplots

The MWE below shows that the solution at [How can I change the font family in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots/33329) does not cover all the cases. The digits in the plot itself and the subscript in math mode in the title need further attention.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%deal with warning message in log
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{
  tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
name, footprint
Google search,  0.2
Movie download, 20
}\carbonfootprints

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

\begin{axis}[ 
      xbar, xmin=0,
      tick style={draw=none},
      width=8cm, height=3cm, 
      title={Estimated carbon footprint, g CO${}_2$}, 
      enlarge y limits=0.3,
      ytick=data,
      yticklabel style={align=right},
      yticklabels={
        2. Google search, 
        1. Movie download
      },
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
    ]
    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=footprint, y expr=\coordindex] 
             {\carbonfootprints};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you add `font=\sffamily\sansmath` to the `tikzpicture` options (or the `axis` options), all text will be in sans serif, without you having to find all relevant styles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%deal with warning message in log
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
name, footprint
Google search,  0.2
Movie download, 20
}\carbonfootprints

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath]

\begin{axis}[ 
      xbar, xmin=0,
      tick style={draw=none},
      width=8cm, height=3cm, 
      title={Estimated carbon footprint, g CO${}_2$}, 
      enlarge y limits=0.3,
      ytick=data,
      yticklabel style={align=right},
      yticklabels={
        2. Google search, 
        1. Movie download
      },
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]
    \addplot [fill=red] table [x=footprint, y expr=\coordindex] 
             {\carbonfootprints};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You solved a problem of mine: Making Tikz Graphics with serif fonts for the report, and making them with sans-serif fonts as standalone image for presentations. Including the `sansmath` and `\tikzset{every picture/.style={font=\sffamily\sansmath}}` into the preamble of the standalone tex file did the trick without the need of changing the original tikz code for the image.

Comment: Same here. Including `[font=\sffamily\sansmath]` in the tikzpicture-options made the`\pgfplotsset`-definitions regarding sans-serif usage (axis and tick labels, legend) superfluous. Additionally, it solved the problem of displaying an additional node text in sans-serif font (which the pgfplotsset, in my case, did not).