# Same font style for all tikzpicture elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I want all labels and elements of a tikzpicture barplot to have the same font style.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \sffamily
    \begin{center}
        {\Large \textbf{Title}}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
            \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\sffamily]
            \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
                yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
                xtick={1, 2},
                xticklabels={A, B},
                ]
                \addplot [color = red]coordinates {
                    (1,1000000) 
                    (2,2000000) 
                };                          
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I almost got it, but the power of ten is still in serif font.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\sffamily` is not enough because numbers and labels are in math mode.

The package  `sansmath` will do the tick.

The  command `\sansmath`  behaves as `\boldmath` does.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{sansmath}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \sffamily
    \begin{center}
        {\Large \textbf{Title}} 
            
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sansmath\sffamily] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
                yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
                xtick={1, 2},       
                xticklabels={A, B},
                ]
                \addplot [color = red]coordinates {
                    (1,1000000) 
                    (2,2000000) 
                };                          
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

See [Change font family in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118681/161015)