# Setting all nodes to use \sffamily without overriding font size

Tags: fonts, pgfplots, legend

In my document, I want all labels in tikz and pgfplots graphics to use sans-serif, so I use `\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}}`.  This works.  However, when I use this, inside my axis environment, `legend style={font=\tiny}` no longer has any effect.  The document below produces an axis where the legend has the normal font size.  How do I set all nodes to use sans-serif fonts, while still being able to tweak the font size for legends on a per-case basis?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={font=\tiny}]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1) (3.5, -1)};
\addlegendentry{Test}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

True effect (sans-serif fonts, but instruction on legend font size ineffective):

[image: Figure does not use a tiny legend font]

Effect with the `font=\sffamily` instruction disabled (serif fonts with tiny legend font size):

[image: Figure does use a tiny legend font]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need this for every node from every Ti*k*Z-picture? Your approach is quite harsh.

Please have a look on my MWE and see, if this is feasable for you.

Off-topic: You have been loading Ti*k*Z for three times. `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`, `\usepackage{tikz}`, and `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` which loads it as well.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,tick label style = {font=\sffamily} % see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33329 if also needed for numbers.
    ,every axis label = {font=\sffamily}
    ,legend style = {font=\tiny\sffamily}
    ,label style = {font=\sffamily}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1) (3.5, -1)};
    \addlegendentry{Test}
    \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

The problem with your approach was that you have been using the option `font` twice. Once you use `font=\sffamily` and once `font=\tiny`. You are using the `.append style` macro, but this will append the whole option to your drawing. If an option is set twice, Ti*k*Z will take the last occurrence.

If you need to set all nodes in your document to `\sffamily`, you will have to define your own options such as `fontsize=` and `fontfamily=` (maybe already existing) or you define a real "font append" as you have been trying to do. This will look like the following (credits to Henry DeYoung):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
    ,font append/.style={font/.expand once=\tikz@textfont #1}
    ,font append/.value required
    }
\makeatother
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font append=\sffamily}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[%
    legend style={font=\tiny}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1) (3.5, -1)};
    \addlegendentry{Test}
    \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

Both MWEs result in:

[image]

Comment: That might work, but why does my approach not?

Comment: @gerrit In your approach `\tiny\sffamily` would work. By setting it to just `\tiny` you'Re overwriting the `\sffamily`command you used before.

Comment: @gerrit Please see my update. I hope, it gets clear. Ronny's suggestion is absolutely right. I just suggested that you do not want to set that manually for a second time.

Comment: In general is `\sffamily` preferred to be used in `tikzpictures`?

Answer (score 1):

The legend is set as a matrix. So you could change the style of the cell nodes using `nodes={...}`.

You could define a new command

```
\newcommand\mynodefont{\sffamily}
```

and use this command for all nodes

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\mynodefont}}
```

and inside the `nodes` key for the legend:

```
legend style={nodes={font=\mynodefont\tiny}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\newcommand\mynodefont{\sffamily}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\mynodefont}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={nodes={font=\mynodefont\tiny}}
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,1) (3.5, -1)};
\addlegendentry{Test}
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```