# How to use sansmath to specify the font for tick label in pgfplots with xelatex?

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, unicode-math

I learned from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-in-pgfplots) that the package sansmath can be used to change the font of tick label by setting option `tick label style`. Now I want to set the tick label font to be sans serif font while other fonts such as legend font and label font are still serif fonts. I use xelatex and unicode-math. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    tick label style={font=\sansmath\sffamily},
}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,3)};
        \addlegendentry{$n=1$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the tick label font is in the italic form. I want to make only the tick label font is sans serif and all other positions are still serif fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if I am on the right track, and will be happy to delete this. I also do not have `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` installed, but hope this is not too relevant. I am wondering if you are looking for

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    xticklabel={\begin{sansmath}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\end{sansmath}},
    yticklabel={\begin{sansmath}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\end{sansmath}},
}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,3)};
        \addlegendentry{$n=1$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I make the tick label font to be the upright?

Comment: @Ice0cean E.g. with `xticklabel={\sffamily\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},
    yticklabel={\sffamily\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},`.