# How to change axis tick label font to Arial when using pgfplots to draw a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

### [image]

I can change the main font in the preamble using

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

but it only works for the legend but not axis tick label, I've installed Arial font.
I don't want to use

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{sansmath}
```

for they are not the same as Arial. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33325

Comment: If you can load `unicode-math`, it should be able to set your `\mathrm` font to Arial. (Should happen automatically if you set the main font, or use `\setmathrm`.) You can also `\setsansfont` and use `\mathsfup`.

Comment: @nidhin, I tried that, but the {helvet} package derived font was not the totally same as Arial

Comment: @Davislor, thank you, but unicode-math don't work.